# IONIC Storage is null when i call storage.get(key)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-storage

Im trying to set the user info when i login into the app and when i go to the profile page im trying to retrieve the data.

To set and get the user info Im using a separate service

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    private loginUrl = UrlService.APIURL+'/login/';
    userEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private storage:Storage) { }


    public setStorageUser(user:any){

         return this.storage.set('user', user);

    }
    public getStorageUser():Promise<any>{

            return this.storage.get('user');

    }




}
```

Setting value on Login Page

```
this.loginService.setStorageUser(userData).then(()=>{

        this.navController.setRoot(HomePage);

        });
```

Retrieving the user data on Profile page

```
this.loginService.getStorageUser().then((user)=>{
       console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    });
```

App module page on my app

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { AndroidExoplayer } from '@ionic-native/android-exoplayer';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import {PayPal} from '@ionic-native/paypal';

import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import {ChannelListPage} from '../pages/channel-list/channel-list';
import {ListsPage} from '../pages/lists/lists';

import { LoginService } from '../providers/login.service';
import { UserService } from '../providers/user.service';
import { FileServiceProvider } from '../providers/file-service';
import { CategoryService } from '../providers/category.service';
import { ChannelService } from '../providers/channel.service';
import { SubscriptionService } from '../providers/subscription.service';

import {SideMenuPage} from '../pages/side-menu/side-menu';
import { CategoryPage} from '../pages/category/category';
import { ChannelsPage} from '../pages/channels/channels';
import { FavoritePage} from '../pages/favorite/favorite';
import { ChannelPage} from '../pages/channel/channel';
import { CategoryDetailPage} from '../pages/category-detail/category-detail';
import {PlayerPage} from '../pages/player/player';
import {RegisterPage} from '../pages/register/register';
import {PaymentPage} from '../pages/payment/payment';
import {ProfilePage} from '../pages/profile/profile';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChannelListPage,
    ListsPage,
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    SideMenuPage,
    FavoritePage,
    CategoryPage,
    ChannelsPage,
    CategoryDetailPage,
    PlayerPage,
    ChannelPage,
    RegisterPage,
    PaymentPage,
    ProfilePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ChannelListPage,
    ListsPage,
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    SideMenuPage,
    CategoryPage,
    ChannelsPage,
    FavoritePage,
    CategoryDetailPage,
    PlayerPage,
    ChannelPage,
    RegisterPage,
    PaymentPage,
    ProfilePage
  ],
  providers: [

    File,
    FileTransfer,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AppAvailability,
    AndroidExoplayer,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    FileServiceProvider,
    LoginService,
    CategoryService,
    ChannelService,
    SubscriptionService,
    UserService,
     PayPal
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I always get null user, help!!

Comment: Hi! could you show more code from your service (where you set and get user info)? Specifically: are you injecting Storage in the constructor? Are you running this code after the deviceReady event?

Comment: Thanks for your early response, i update the code.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Could you log the value of user before attempting to save it?
Like this:
public setStorageUser(user:any){
         console.log(user);
         return this.storage.set('user', user);

    }

Comment: I already logged the value in my home page after login and i get the information of the user, but when i go to my side menu and click to the perfil option it returns null, and when i tried to log the value in app.componet.ts is like at app.componet level storage  is null because my side menu  is configured in my app componet, Im not sure

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem because Storage should have only one instance within your app. Unless you are configuring the Storage module in multiple Modules in your app.
So, if I understand correctly you can retrieve the user info from storage with that same code in your home page, but not in your side menu? In this case I would need to see the declaration of each component

Comment: Do you need to see the app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes. But if you also declare pages as independent modules, I would need to see those. Or show me the file structure pointing the components where you are using storage

Comment: Im just using one module the app.module.ts file and everything is there, i will put my  app.module in the code above

Comment: Sorry, i found the problem. I was cleaning the storage in other process :(